# Unable to set  icon for the menu item using ItemContainerStyle

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, menuitem, itemcontainerstyle

I am trying to set the Icon of my menu item like this -

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Image
              x:Key="ReportIconImage" Height="20" Width="20"
              Source="/Resource/flag.png"/>
        <Image
              x:Key="ReportIconImage1" Height="20" Width="20"
              Source="/Resource/flag.png"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Menu Height="22" Margin="0,9,0,0" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Menu">
            <MenuItem Header="Save" ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter  
                        Property="Icon" 
                        Value="{StaticResource ReportIconImage}">
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit">
            <MenuItem Header="Undo"/>                   
            <MenuItem Header="Redo"/>                    
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Cut"/>                    
            <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>                    
            <MenuItem  Header="Paste"/>
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter  
                         Property="Icon" 
                         Value="{StaticResource ReportIconImage1}">
                </Setter>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

but the icon for only last menu item is displayed and not for first two.

[image]

Sample application - http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/akjoshi/Samples/WPFMenuItemBugSample.zip

Can anyone provide the reason for this behavior and possible solutions/workarounds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you've used an `Image` in your resources. An `Image` is a control and - like any other control - can only have one parent. By default, WPF will attempt to share resources across all consumers. Thus, the last `MenuItem` "wins" custodial rights to the `Image` and the other `MenuItem`'s aren't even allowed weekend visitations.

To rectify this, you could either set the `Image` to be non-shared:

```
<Image x:Shared="False" .../>
```

Or, better still, manifest your image resource as the appropriate [`ImageSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.aspx) subclass and share that instead:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="ReportIconImage" Uri="/Resource/flag.png"/>
...
<Setter Property="Icon">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Image Source="{StaticResource ReportIconImage}"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Thanks Kent, but unfortunately both the solutions doesn't work. There is no impact of first one and second one generates following exception :-            Cannot add content of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to an object of type 'System.Object'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' in markup file 'Sample;component/window1.xaml' Line 27 Position 34.

Comment: In case it helps, I have uploaded the sample application reproducing this problem in the question;

Comment: @akjoshi: thanks for the repro. Switching your project to WPF 4 allows my first suggestion to work, so there must be a bug in 3.5. As for my second suggestion, that won't work because WPF is attempting to use the same Image across all MenuItems, in much the way I described in my answer. If there was an `IconTemplate` property, you'd use that. Unfortunately, `MenuItem` isn't fine-grained enough to have one, so I can only suggest overriding the `Template` instead. Frustrating to say the least.

Answer (score 5):

A little late, but here is a solution that worked for me.

I used a converter to make a new image for each menuitem:

```
class PathToImageConverter:IValueConverter
{
    object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string path = "Data/Icons/" + value + ".png";
        Image img = new Image {Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative))};
        return img;
    }

    object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
   <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PathToImageConverter1}}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to just add an icon property to each menu item directly, without using a style? Maybe I'm missing something, but this is what I've done in my apps.

```
<Grid>
    <Menu Height="22" Margin="0,9,0,0" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="Menu">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="/Resourceflag.png"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>

            <MenuItem Header="Save" ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="/Resourceflag.png"/>
            </MenuItem.Icon>

            <MenuItem Header="Undo"/>                   
            <MenuItem Header="Redo"/>                    
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Cut"/>                    
            <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>                    
            <MenuItem  Header="Paste"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```